# Getting empty Response from get request from Rest service in MVC 4 Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, rest, httprequest

I have a simple method that create a List of objects Team, convert it to Json and then returns it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var teams = new List<Team>() {
       new Team{ Name = "Caracas F.C", City = "Caracas", Id = 1},
       new Team{ Name = "Millonarios", City = "Bogota", Id = 2},
       new Team{ Name = "Independiente", City = "Bogota", Id = 3}};

    var jsonData = new { teamsData = teams };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I go to that URL (http://prototypeteam.apphb.com/ , check it out by yourself), I can clearly see the Json

> {"teamsData":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Caracas F.C","City":"Caracas"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Millonarios","City":"Bogota"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Independiente","City":"Bogota"}]}

But when I try to get the Json using JQuery it returns without response:

```
self.allTeams = ko.observableArray();
    $.getJSON("http://prototypeteam.apphb.com/", function (data) {
        var mappedTeams = $.map(data.teamsData, function (item) {
            return new TeamViewModel(item);
        });
        self.allTeams(mappedTeams);
});

TeamViewModel = function (data) {
    self = this;
    self.Id = data.Id;
    self.Name = data.Name;
    self.City = data.City;
}
```

This is what I'm getting using Mozilla's Firebug.

[image]

If someone can please help me understand why this is happening. I don't get why I see the Json clearly at the URL but JQuery seems not to understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: And this is all on the same domain, or is your script not running from the same domain ?

Comment: You may need to explicitly append the method name on your call to return your Json rather than just passing the URL. Also try the full ajax() instead of the getJson short code. Then in ajax() set the type to "post" and pass an empty data.

Comment: @adeneo no, Is not the same domain.

Comment: @User970008 I already try it but didn't worked

Comment: You're experiencing the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of javascript. You can not get the content from external site unless that site supports CORS or JSONP, neither of which seems to be supported by that site.

Comment: @adeneo, as you can see the api is uploaded in AppHarbor, but I'm doing the get request from a file in my computer, does the Same origin policy will still affect from my pc?

Comment: @adeneo, thanks that was the problem, I manage to solve it, but you should answer the question with your comment.

Comment: @Guillelon - sure, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the same origin policy.

Javascript has a security measure where you can't get content from external URL's, you can only get files with ajax from the same domain.

There are two excepions:

1. JSONP. As jsonp isn't really ajax, but inserts a script tag into the DOM like any other script tag, it avoids the same origin policy. The service has to support this and wrap the json string inside a function that executes once the script has loaded.
2. CORS. Enabling CORS headers lets you use scripts from other domains, but again this has to be set on the serverside.

There's also the option to use a service like Yahoo YQL or Pipes, but that just gets the content and wraps it in either JSONP or adds a CORS header, so it uses one of the two options above.

The same origin policy applies everwhere, even if you're running everything on the localhost and try to get a file from the web, the same origin policy won't allow it, as the URL's don't match.